# Roku Pay Web Services API

Tags: json, push-notification, roku

Has anyone ever used Roku Pay Web Services API using push notifications ? If so can you please explain how you did it with a code example? I want to use this API to send me a notification every time a transaction is made.

This is the documentation to the API
https://developer.roku.com/fr-fr/docs/developer-program/roku-pay/implementation/roku-web-service.md